# Не могу получить HTML сайта

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

Пытаюсь получить HTML сайта, но выпадает ошибка. В чем может быть дело? Сервер работает без проблем.

Как подключаюсь

```
 Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.example.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl");
 Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.example.conscrypt.OpenSSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
 URL url = new URL("https://dev.avest.by/");
 HttpsURLConnection connection = prepareConnection(url);
 connection.connect();
 print_content(connection);

private HttpsURLConnection prepareConnection(final URL verifierURL) throws IOException {
    final HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) verifierURL.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    connection.setHostnameVerifier(this);
    return connection;
}

private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con) {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String input;
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(input);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: POST / HTTP/1.1
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:54)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at com.example.conscrypt.activity.MainActivity.print_content(MainActivity.java:65)
W/System.err:     at com.example.conscrypt.activity.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:20)
W/System.err:     at com.example.conscrypt.activity.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: URL не рабочий, попробуйте его открыть в браузере.

Comment: url рабочий, только для SSL используется свой алгоритм шифрования. Браузеры и прочие не знают его, в приложение подключены библиотеки для работы с этим алгоритмом, но почему-то выдаёт такую ошибку :(

Comment: https на сайте не работает. http пробуйте.

Comment: Ну и могу предположить, сайт не отдает страничку на POST запрос. Попробуйте GET

Comment: попробуйте для начала получить страницу каким-либо другим путем, не на Android